# CRS to use to georeference an 19th century Ordnance Survey 1 Inch map

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system, georeferencing, ordnance-survey

I have a raster of an Ordnance Survey 1 inch map that was surveyed in 1843-57 and subsequently revised in 1896 and published in 1898: [Sheet 50 - Hawes](https://maps.nls.uk/view/101169413). When georeferenced in QGIS using OSGB36/British National Grid, EPSG:27700 the resulting map raster is skewed. I don't think that this is due to inaccurate georeferencing - I used multiple ref. points and the skewing is consistent across the whole map. I'd like the georeferenced raster to preserve the map's original shape and orientation. Is there a CRS that will do this?

Edit: I was able to fix the skew by rotating the canvas (bottom RHS of screen).

Comment: Are the lat and long lines parallel and equally spaced on the original image? The grids on the side look like a regular set of lat-long coordinates, so you can possibly georeference using just the lat-long coordinates of the corners. These won't be WGS84 lat-long coordinates though. I'm not sure what was used in the 1840s. A small translation may be needed for your required accuracy...